# What is the difference between msg.sender.balance and address(this).balance?

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain

What is the difference between `msg.sender.balance` and `address(this).balance`?

when I run the code the output

`msg.sender.balance` = 99

`address(this).balance` = 0

```js
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
    pragma solidity >=0.7.1 <0.9.0;
    contract test{
        uint public myBalance1=msg.sender.balance;
        uint public myBalance2=address(this).balance;
        
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`address(this).balance` is the balance of the smart contract itself.

`msg.sender.balance` is the balance of the user that made the transaction, and if `msg.sender` is another contract, then it's the balance of that other contract.

`this` refers to the contract instance that is executing. `msg.sender` is the user or contract that just called the other contract.

I you call the contract, then `msg.sender` is you and `msg.sender.balance` is the balance of your address, the one that you used to send the transaction. `this`, inside a contract, is the contract that you just called, not you.

If you call a `A` and that contract calls another contract `B`, then `msg.sender` inside `B` will not be you but will be `A`'s contract address. Inside `A`, `msg.sender` is you, because you are the one that called it, but inside `B`, `msg.sender` is `A`, because a called `B`.

Comment: im who call and deploy contract with the same address, why not the same balance output

Comment: Because your account and the smart contract you deploy are two different entities, with their own balance. If you want to see a balance on your smart contract, then you need to implement the `receive() external payable` or `fallback() external payable` or any payable function to accept ether on your contract, which, by default, does not accept ether unless you define a `payable` function.